# The command "cordova platform add Android --save" doesn't work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I use [Ionic 5](https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-ionic-5/). I build Android_App. But I get an error. I used the command:

```
$ ionic cordova build Android
```

"platform add" is executed in the process.

```
$ cordova platform add Android --save
```

As a result, a 404 error is displayed.

```
kuniatsu$ ionic cordova build Android
? Platform Android is not installed! Would you like to install it? Yes
> cordova platform add Android --save
Using cordova-fetch for Android
Failed to fetch platform Android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Android - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'Android@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kuniatsu/.npm/_logs/2020-04-16T09_55_40_443Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova platform add Android --save exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.


kuniatsu$ cat ../../../.npm/_logs/2020-04-16T09_48_54_083Z-debug.log
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/kuniatsu/.nodebrew/node/v13.11.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/kuniatsu/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'Android',
1 verbose cli   '--production',
1 verbose cli   '--save-exact'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.7
3 info using node@v13.11.0
4 verbose npm-session 46caa2142033cf3e
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/Android 128ms
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/Android 30ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for Android@latest 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Android - Not found
10 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
11 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2522ms
12 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Android - Not found
12 verbose stack     at /Users/kuniatsu/.nodebrew/node/v13.11.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:104:15
12 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
13 verbose statusCode 404
14 verbose pkgid Android@latest
15 verbose cwd /Users/kuniatsu/src/ionic/App
16 verbose Darwin 19.3.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/kuniatsu/.nodebrew/node/v13.11.0/bin/node" "/Users/kuniatsu/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm" "install" "Android" "--production" "--save-exact"
18 verbose node v13.11.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.7
20 error code E404
21 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/Android - Not found
22 error 404
23 error 404 'Android@latest' is not in the npm registry.
24 error 404 Your package name is not valid, because
25 error 404 1. name can no longer contain capital letters
26 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
27 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

What do I need to successfully install the platform and complete the build?

Comment: android is small letter and not capitalized, its considering Android as new platform other than android

Comment: "$ ionic cordova build android"　My problem is solved.